# After sorting the rank, how to select one record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with my database. And I want to sort by download and rank it. After that I want to select one record by id.

I know how to rank it.

```
SELECT id, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY "downLoad" DESC) rank FROM gameinfo;
```

[image: result above sql]

So I try to use 'WHERE' to get one result

```
SELECT id, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY "downLoad" DESC) rank FROM gameinfo WHERE id='9b9df0c5-9906-4444-b30a-9b64ff8fea94';
```

[image: wrong result]

I got one record but the result was rank=1
I expect 2.

Right now I get all the gameinfo and ranked it all. After that, I search the id from JavaScript to get the right rank, but is there a way just using SQL to get one record?

Comment: the `WHERE` is evaluated before your window function ranks the records resulting in only one record to rank. You could put the `SELECT` in a subquery and do a  `WHERE` over the main query to keep all records in your dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the WHERE is evaluated before your window function ranks the records resulting in only one record to rank. You could put the SELECT in a subquery and do a WHERE over the main query to keep all records in your dataset.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
       (
           SELECT id, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY "downLoad" DESC) rank 
           FROM gameinfo
        ) a 
WHERE ID = '9b9df0c5-9906-4444-b30a-9b64ff8fea94'
```

Comment: In case of ties you could use `LIMIT` as Tim described above or use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`  in order to get 1 record returned if you only want one record and ID is non unique in your dataset.

Comment: @tim op needs the rank of a given user

Comment: @SalmanA I see it now.  Wish the OP could have shown some data.

Answer (score 1):

The answer proposed by HansG will run a window function over the whole table just to select one row, which is inefficient.

If you just want to select one row and know its rank, then... the rank is simply the number of rows with more downloads.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM gameinfo WHERE downloads > (
    SELECT downloads FROM gameinfo WHERE id=...);
```

If you already selected the row to display it, you can replace the subquery with the actual value.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to use your SQL too.